# Beautiful Dnd is not working with react@18

Tags: reactjs, npm, installation, react-dnd

I am trying to include beautiful dnd package in my project but i got error while installing the package.[image]

Please tell me if there is any other package like it or the solution of this error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try installing `@hello-pangea/dnd` from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hello-pangea/dnd) with the following command:

```
npm i @hello-pangea/dnd
```

Later on, pretty much everything else is the same, you only change your imports from:

> `import { DragDropContext } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';`

to

> `import { DragDropContext } from '@hello-pangea/dnd';`

#### Their NPM page:

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hello-pangea/dnd

#### And their Github Repo:

> https://github.com/hello-pangea/dnd

Comment: Sadly OP didn't mark this answer as the solution. Worked for me using react 18.2.0

Comment: Agreed, worked great for me too. Not sure why beautiful DND gets so many downloads when it is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing with `--legacy-peer-deps` as suggested [here](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/2408)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Thanks,
Replacing 'react-beautiful-dnd' with [hellopangea](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hello-pangea/dnd) worked for me. I am using React with TypeScript, using Vite. HelloPangea already has built in support for TypeScript.
Although there is a warning that pops up in browser console, but the app runs fine. Will update the answer if faced any other issues.
Cheers!

@hello-pangea/dndDroppable setup issue [droppableId:"TodosRemove"]:DroppableProvided > placeholder could not be found.**Please be sure to add the {provided.placeholder} React Node as a child of your Droppable**.More information: https://github.com/hello-pangea/dnd/blob/main/docs/api/droppable.md

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).